# Discrete subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

Let $\Lambda$ be  a closed subgroup of real vector space $V$. If $\Lambda$ is not discrete, is it possible to conclude from this that there exists vector $v \in \Lambda$ such that $xv \in \Lambda$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$.  Not sure what you mean by "Let $\Lambda$ be closed a subgroup of real..."

Comment: @lulu, i mean, that it is closed in Euclidian topology. And thus $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed. it is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is $V$ supposed to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: @EricWofsey, it is, but i expected it is inessential.

Comment: It is essential.  For one thing, if $V$ is not finite-dimensional you have to specify the topology on it since there is no canonical topology.

Comment: @EricWofsey, right. Thank you

Comment: A subgroup of a Hausdorff group does not have to be closed...consider $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true if $V$ is finite-dimensional.  Indeed, since $\Lambda$ is not discrete, there is a sequence $(v_n)$ of nonzero vectors in $\Lambda$ which converge to $0$.  Since the unit sphere is compact, by passing to a subsequence you can assume $\frac{v_n}{\|v_n\|}$ converges to a vector $v$.  For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, you can then approximate $xv$ arbitrarily well by elements of the form $mv_n$ in $\Lambda$ by choosing $n$ sufficiently large and an integer $m$ such that $m\|v_n\|$ is close to $x$.

On the other hand, this is not true for infinite-dimensional topological vector spaces.  For instance, let $V=\ell^\infty$ and let $\Lambda$ be the subgroup of bounded sequences of the form $(a_n/n)$ where each $a_n$ is an integer.